# Android Compose: can composables store more than a single state?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

from the official docs ([Managing State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state))

> Composable functions can store a single object in memory by using the remember composable. A value computed by remember is stored in the composition during initial composition, and that stored value is returned during recomposition. You can use remember to store both mutable and immutable objects.

so a single `remember` per composable, but I've found code online that used more than a single state in a composable, actually from an official source :[DropdownMenu](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/dropdownmenu/)

```
@Composable
fun DropdownDemo() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val items = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
    val disabledValue = "B"
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)) {
        Text(items[selectedIndex],modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable(onClick = { expanded = true }).background(
            Color.Gray))
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(
                Color.Red)
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    selectedIndex = index
                    expanded = false
                }) {
                    val disabledText = if (s == disabledValue) {
                        " (Disabled)"
                    } else {
                        ""
                    }
                    Text(text = s + disabledText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code works fine, but it stores two states, doesn't it ?!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that documentation meant, that using one `remember` you can store one object, not that each composable can't have multiple `remember` values.